# ssas alias doesn't work

Tags: ssas

We registered a cname to be able to use SSAS with an alias.

It works on client computer but not directly from the server.
How to correct this ?
We don't use default ssas port

Comment: What command(s) did you issue (to connect?) on the client and what command(s) did you issue on the server? The more detail you provide, the more likely it is you'll receive a good answer!

Comment: See comment above!

Comment: We tried with SSMS